# how to access webcam on windows phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, webcam

how can i access webcam through windows phone 7 emulator to take the pic  and save the image in gallery of emulator.
i have seen [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/windowsphone?query=webcam%20picture&Refinement=184&ac=3#refinementChanges=203&pageNumber=1&showMore=false) but this api doesnt work.
please suugest an api that will implement webcam on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do it.  Debug using a physical device instead.